# Angular 6 mat-form-field with mat-select not selecting any values

Tags: angular6, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I am new to Angular 6, and I am working on a project where I am using material design with reactive form which uses form control. So the problem I am facing is that all  other fields are working fine except mat-select, where it properly display the drop-down content but when i select it, the selected values are not reflected in form control.
And mat-select data are coming from back-end

Here is my html code:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-select placeholder="Source City" formControlName="sourceCityControl" required [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">
          {{city.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error>
        Source City <strong> Required </strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <br> <br>

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-select placeholder="Destination City" formControlName="destinationCityControl" required [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">
          {{city.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error>
        Destination City <strong> Required </strong>
      </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field> 
    <!-- other form elements  -->
    <!-- to check form elements -->
    {{profileForm.value | json}}
```

And here is my TypeScript file code:

```
public cities = [];
minDate = new Date();
nextdate = this.minDate.getUTCDate();
nextmonth = this.minDate.getUTCMonth();
nextyear = this.minDate.getFullYear();
maxDate = new Date(this.nextyear, this.nextmonth + 1, this.nextdate);
host: Oldoffer;
offerModel: any;
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _offerService: 
OfferRideService, private router: Router, private editService: EditService) 
{ }
test1: string;
test2: Date;
test3: Date;
profileForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.nextdate);
this._offerService.getCities().subscribe(data => this.cities = data);
this.editService.getHost().subscribe((data) => {
  this.host = data;
  this.test1 = this.host.date.toString();
  this.test2 = new Date(this.test1.slice(0, 19) + 'Z');
  this.test3 = new Date(this.test2.getFullYear(), this.test2.getUTCMonth(), 
  this.test2.getUTCDate())
  this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
    sourceCityControl: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    destinationCityControl: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dateControl: new FormControl(this.test3, Validators.required),
    seatsControl: new FormControl(this.host.noOfSeats, [Validators.required, 
    Validators.min(1), Validators.max(4)]),
    amountControl: new FormControl(this.host.amount, [Validators.required, 
    Validators.min(0), Validators.max(2000)]),
    acControl: new FormControl(this.host.preference.ac),
    musicControl: new FormControl(this.host.preference.music),
    smokingControl: new FormControl(this.host.preference.smoking),
    petsControl: new FormControl(this.host.preference.pets)
  });
})
}//other code omitted
```

Any help and suggestions??
Thanks ...

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` element that wraps all of your form controls with the proper `formGroup` directive? [The docs site](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-associating-the-formgroup-model-and-view) has an example of this.

Comment: yes I have that, sorry forgot paste in this question.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your problem to it's simplest form and here's what you're missing: you might be missing a `<form>` element from your other formContorls so make sure you always keep an eye on on the console. It's gonna be your best friend if you're new to angular. Also when building FormGroups, look at the documentation for it because that's not a good way to do it.

Just follow the example I build for you and it should solve your problems: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbihkv

Comment: Thanks man you saved my day, but can you just tell what was wrong with my approach and why do we need to do it like this, because as a beginner I don't see any difference.